# Authentication plugin error when connecting to mySQL

Tags: mysql

I am learning PHP and just installed Sequel Pro. I am trying to make a connection but it
is giving a long error but last line says

> MySQL said: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be
> loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2):
> image not found

Before this, I was getting

> MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)

and I found `mysql.server start` on another SO thread but now it is Authentication plugin error.

I am using MacOS Big Sur on M1 chipset. Not sure why I am getting the error or how to fix it

Comment: the version of sequel pro you are using is not supporting the connection to newer mysql version. You can either use the legacy authentication method in mysql or use a newer tool that supports the new and more secure authentication method

Comment: @LelioFaieta what is ur suggestion

Comment: have you read the second sentence in my comment?

Comment: @LelioFaieta yes but I do not know how to either use legacy auth method in mysql or which latest tool to use

Comment: a tool that is not sequel pro that is compatible with mysql server 8 or the answer below that moves you to the legacy method

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the `ALTER` command to change the password instead which would help prevent the authentication plugin caching_sha2_password:

```
ALTER USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Comment: Hello, how would I get into mysql interface if i cannot log in mysql