php password encryption after upgrade from mySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.4
As part of upgrading MySQL from 5.7 to 8.4, my server is now configured so that each defined user's login will ask for caching_sha2_password encryption.  I do not want to enable mysql_native_passwords in the MySQL configuration file because they are removed in version 9 of the database.
This is not the same question as MySQL Authentication Plugin Issues on macOS.  That question deals with trying to make native passwords work in a MySQL version 9 environment and the suggested answer is to backrev to MySQL version 8 and enable native passwords.  That is not what I want.
The database is correctly configured to use caching_sha2_passwords:
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| user             | host      | plugin                |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| mysql.infoschema | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.session    | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.sys        | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| root             | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

My PHP version is 8.3.12.
I can connect to the database inside PHPStorm when the PHPStorm database connection is configured for SSL.
DBMS: MySQL (ver. 8.4.3)
Case sensitivity: plain=lower, delimited=lower
Driver: MySQL Connector/J (ver. mysql-connector-j-8.2.0 (Revision: 06a1f724497fd81c6a659131fda822c9e5085b6c), JDBC4.2)

Ping: 12 ms
SSL: yes

My php.ini has the following plugins enabled for the mysqlnd (mysql native driver):
Loaded plugins => mysqlnd,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password,auth_plugin_caching_sha2_password,auth_plugin_sha256_password

Creating a database connection using mysqli_connect (e.g. the native driver) works fine.
BUT, creating a PDO database connection throws the following exception:
PDOException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1524] Plugin 'mysql_native_password' is not loaded

There are only 2 lines of configuration for Pdo_mysql in php.ini:
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
pdo_mysql.default_socket=

Why is PDO trying to use the mysql_native_password plugin? Is there some additional configuration in the php.ini I need to do in order to enable PDO to send sha2-encrypted passwords?
Thanks in advance.

Or this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72162273/authentication-plugin-error-when-connecting-to-mysql
